# Modal pop up AJAX exits when refresh

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

**Here is the situation, I have a AJAX modal pop up, inside my panel is two(2) connected drop down list. One is for Continent, and the other one is for Countries. An example of it is when the user choose Asia, the drop down for countries should have data inside. here is my code for modal pop up and Panel**

```
  <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="Modalpopupextender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="ShowPopUpButton"
        PopupControlID="pnlpopup" CancelControlID="CancelButton" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
     </asp:ModalPopupExtender>

  <asp:Panel ID="pnlpopup" runat="server" BackColor="White" Height="269px" Width="400px"
        OnLoad="pnlpopup_Load">
    <tr>
                <td align="right">
                    Continent:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ContinentDownList" runat="server" 
                        onselectedindexchanged="ContinentDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">
                    Country:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="CountryDropDownList" runat="server">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
            </tr>
      </asp:Panel>
```

**Now my Problem is, When my Modal Pop up loads, When I choose a Continent, the drop down for Countries doesnt load. When I Inserted AutoPostBack="true" to my ContinentDropDown, the Modal Pop Up refreshes, and exits. Ive spend a long time debugging and knowing how to fix this. Help!**

here is my code-behind

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            LoadContinent();
            LoadCountry();
        }
    }

  public void LoadContinent()
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        {

            using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Reader.usp_LoadContinentDropDownList", con))
            {

               com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                con.Open();
                try
                {

                   SqlDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();
                   OwnerGroupDropDownList.DataSource = dr;
                    OwnerGroupDropDownList.DataTextField = "fld_Description";
                    OwnerGroupDropDownList.DataValueField = "fld_ContinentID";

                    ContinentDropDownList.DataBind();
                }
                catch (SqlException)
                {
                    Response.Write("<script>alert('The database has encountered an error. Please try again')</script>");                    }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    Response.Write("<script>alert('The database has encountered an error. Please try again')</script>");                    }
            }

        }
        LoadContinentDropDownList.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("<Select Person Group>", "0")); 
    }


         public void LoadCountry()
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        {

            using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Reader.usp_LoadCountryDropDownList", con))
            {


                com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@fld_ContinentId", SqlDbType.Int));
                com.Parameters["@fld_ContinentId"].Value = ContinentDropDownList.SelectedValue;
                con.Open();

                try
                {

                    SqlDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader();
                    OwnerDropDownList.DataSource = dr;
                    OwnerDropDownList.DataTextField = "fld_Description";
                    OwnerDropDownList.DataValueField = "fld_CountryID";

                    CountryDownList.DataBind();
                }
                catch (SqlException)
                {
                    Response.Write("<script>alert('The database has encountered an error. Please try again')</script>");                    }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                   Response.Write("<script>alert('The database has encountered an error. Please try again')</script>");                    }
            }
        }
         CountryDropDownList.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("<Select Person>", "0")); 
    }

      protected void ContinentDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadContinent();
        LoadCountry();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting the `pnlPopup` panel inside of an ASP.NET `UpdatePanel` control? Now when your dropdown list does a postback, it will be a partial postback since they are both within an `UpdatePanel` and it should maintain the visibility on the popup panel.

Check out [Introduction to the UpdatePanel Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for more information about creating and using the `UpdatePanel`.

When you put controls outside of an `UpdatePanel`, the `AutoPostback="true"` caused a full postback which "reset" the popup panel to hidden, since that is the default state for the modal popup extender's target control.

Comment: I will put UpdatePanel INSIDE the Panel?

Comment: Question, Where will I put the AsyncPostBackTrigger?/

Comment: Here is a tutorial for using `UpdatePanel` with modal popup extender: [How to use ASP.NET AJAX UpdatePanel in ModalPopup](http://jamestsai.net/Blog/post/How-to-use-ASPNET-AJAX-UpdatePanel-in-ModalPopup.aspx). It has been a few years since I have done this so I do not want to get the syntax wrong.

Comment: See the tutorial for where to put the `Triggers`.

Comment: im getting this weird error. 'Microsoft JScript runtime error: Sys.InvalidOperationException: Handler was not added through the Sys.UI.DomEvent.addHandler method.'